# how to play music without pressing a button flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-audio-query

I was looking for a way to play music in flutter without pressing a button, but I can't find a way, does someone know how to do that

**UPDATE**

I've tried using `initstate()`, but when I implement this, the music would just stop at the middle

this is the current code I have for the `initstate()`

```
final player = AudioPlayer();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance?.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) async{
      if(!player.playing) {
        await player.setAsset("assets/mainmusic.mp3");
        await player.setLoopMode(LoopMode.all);
        await player.play();
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: It is not clear when you like to play the music , Can you update the question including more details and current code-snippet

Comment: Hello @Yeasin Sheikh, I edited the question, I hope the question is clearer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using statelesswidget, switch to a stateful widget.
Then inside the State put following code.

```dart
@override
void initState(){
      'put your music play function'
      super.initState();
}
```

Comment: I did that @Bishop03 but it usually just stops in the middle of the song

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).